# How can I remove null values within a pandas dataframe if I want to use a list defined as an object within the parameters?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

How can I remove null values within a pandas dataframe if I want to use a list defined as an object? Here is an example of what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work.

> "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dropna'"

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

file_loc = 'path/file.xlsx'
sheets = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name = sheets,usecols="Q").dropna()
print(df)
```

Comment: when you pass a list of `sheets` to `read_excel`, you get a dictionary `{'a': dfa, 'b': dfb, ...}`, So you would need to do a dictionary comprehension to drop the nan: `read = pd.read_excel(...); out = {key: value.dropna() for key, value in read.items()}`.